# How do I plot noise gain of an op amp circuit in SPICE?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, gain

How is an AC analysis of the noise gain of an op amp circuit plotted in LTspice?

---

This is a follow-on question to a prior question here: [What is noise gain, really? And how is it determined in the general case?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252089/what-is-noise-gain-really-and-how-is-it-determined-in-the-general-case)

Comment: Between this question and the previous one I'm sure, when the curtain lifts, you'll see that you are making a massive big deal out of something that is as plain as day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plotting the noise gain of an op amp circuit is not too challenging if that's the only trace you want. You simply insert an AC voltage source at the non-inverting terminal, remove (short) any other signal source, and perform an AC analysis.

For a simple non-inverting amplifier circuit this is simply changing the signal source to an AC source and plotting `V(out)/V(v+)`. If you use an AC amplitude of 1, it's simply `V(out)`.

[image]

The violet trace below exactly overlays the yellow trace beneath it, showing that the simpler `V(out)` expression is equivalent when the test signal is AC 1.

[image]

If the \$+\$ terminal is grounded, as it is in an inverting amplifier circuit, you simply insert the `V_test` signal source between the \$+\$ terminal and ground.

---

Things get trickier when we want to plot another gain at the same time. However, if we want to plot noise gain against loop gain, we can take advantage of the relationship between the two:

\begin{align} \\
 NG & = \frac{A_o}{1 + A_o\beta} \\ \\
 LG & = A_o\beta \\ \\
 NG & = \frac{A_o}{1 + LG}
\end{align}

Expressions for both \$A_o\$ and \$LG\$ are available in a loop gain analysis:

\$A_o\$: `V(out) / (V(v+) - V(v-))`

\$LG\$: `V(fb) / V(v-)`

[image]

Combining them we get this expression (note the minus sign in the denominator to account for application to inverting terminal):

\$NG\$: `(V(out) / (V(v+) - V(v-))) / (1 - (V(fb)/V(v-)))`

Using this expression we can plot noise gain (cyan) on the same chart as loop gain (violet) and open loop gain (yellow). Note that SPICE shorts `V_sig` during this `.AC` analysis; `V_sig` can be omitted (shorted) if desired without affecting the plot.

[image]

*A note on the setup for the loop gain analysis:* The `AC 1` signal source provides the perturbation into the high-impedance inverting input. The loop response appears on its other side, the node labeled `fb`. The loop gain is plotted with the expression `V(fb)/V(v-)` in an `.AC` analysis.

Comment: I remember the earlier post. Just out of curiosity, have you visited this linear tech page yet? http://www.linear.com/solutions/1148

Comment: Ooh, no, looks interesting! I'll give it a watch, thanks @jonk :)

Comment: I guess I'm glad I mentioned it. I felt you probably had already seen it, but figured I'd better dot that i, just in case.

Comment: Also consider: http://www.jensign.com/noisegain/index.html

Comment: Yes, that one I *did* come across :)  It didn't help me much at the time because it stuck pretty close to the common case, but I'm sure it's a good introduction overall :) Btw, I added an answer with my findings to that original post, if you didn't see it you might want to check it out.

Comment: @scanny Just a quick note: instead of the lengthy `V(v+) - V(v-))` you can write `V(v+, v-)`.

Comment: Oooh, sweet! I'm *definitely* adding that to my LTspice cheatsheet! Thanks @aconcernedcitizen :)